# Date picker dialog listener

Tags: android, android-widget, datepicker, textview, datepickerdialog

I have to use a DatePickerDialog to get selected date in a textview. When I click the textview the DatePickerDialog should appear.

I wrote this

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateOnDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        datePick.setText(new StringBuilder().append(selectedDay).append("-").append(selectedMonth).append("-").append(selectedYear));
    }
};

datePick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_pick);

    datePick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), dateOnDateSetListener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
```

But its not working.
So with little googling I changed it to this and its working, but I am not able to understand why is it so? Did I mess something in above code

```
datePick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_pick);

    datePick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateOnDateSetListener, 
                     year, monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateOnDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        datePick.setText(new StringBuilder().append(selectedDay).append("-").append(selectedMonth).append("-").append(selectedYear));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But its not working. So with little googling I changed it to this and
>   its working, but I am not able to understand why is it so? Did I mess
>   something in above code

You didn't really mess anything up, you just forgot to call `.show()` on the dialog; i.e.:

```
new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), dateOnDateSetListener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).show();
```

The reason why it works without `.show()` in the second code snippet is because there the `Activity` manages the dialog and will thus take care of calling that method on the dialog that gets returned in `onCreateDialog(int id)`.

Generally I'd recommend the second approach because you don't really want to manage the life cycle of dialogs yourself - simply because it's quite a pain to get it right when your activities get recreated on configuration changes etc. However, for a more modern solution, using fragments, you should look into wrapping the dialog in a [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) (there's also a version in the support library that works on pre-Honeycomb devices).